# How would you translate the concept of "best friend"/"bestie" in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

The expression "plej bona amiko" is long and can feel repetitive. Is there a common or a good way to express the same idea, but in a more concise way?

Answer (score 4):

How about *amikego*?
...........

Answer (score 1):

Slightly tongue-in-cheek: from what I believe the kids these days say, how about *pbao*/*pbaino* (similar to, I think, *bae* in English)? You would probably have to say *plej bona amik(in)o* during a conversation first, to make sure you're understood.

Otherwise I'd agree with Bjørn's suggestion of *amik(in)ego*.